# Transfer Amazon MTurk project from Requester Sandbox to production

Tags: sandbox, production, mechanicalturk

I have created a project on Amazon MTurk Sandbox with a built-in template that I want to transfer to production. However I couldn't find much info on how to do that. Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to copy the project from sandbox to production, you'll follow these two steps:

First, create a new project in production. Give it the same name, reward amount, etc

Next, copy the layout from your sandbox project into your production project.

To do this, go to the Design Layout tab on your Sandbox project.

You'll see the Source button:

[image]

Click the Source button and you'll see this HTML. Copy it and paste it into your production project layout by following the same instructions to open its source.

[image]

Please let us know if you have any additional questions.

Amazon Mechanical Turk